# Populate select in jqgrid filter toolbar

Tags: select, jqgrid

I've tried to populate a dropdownlist with values from my database. I've got the following code in my .js file:

```
function getDropdowndata() {
var sHTML;
var filter;
var url = "dropdown.json";
jQuery.getJSON(url, function (dddata) {
    if (dddata.rows.length > 0) {
        sHTML = "";
        for (x = 0; x < dddata.rows.length; x++) {
            sHTML += (dddata.rows[x].Type + ":" + dddata.rows[x].Type + ";");
        }
        filter = sHTML.substring(0, sHTML.length - 1);
    }
});
return filter;
}
```

And in my Jqgrid list I've got the following:

```
editoptions: { value: ":All;" + getDropdowndata() }
```

The problem I've got with this code is that it seems that the function is being executed too early and because of that the dropdownlist contains nothing.

The reason for my assumption is that if I put an alert inside of the javascript function before the return, the dropdownlist is filled with the values and everything seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the data with a custom function using JSON, you might want to try using the built-in functionality for dynamic select fields (see documentation: [`select` edittype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#select) ). All you do is specify a url where the code for the select element is generated.

```
colModel:[
    {name:'colName',
     editable:true,
     edittype:'select',
     formatter:'select',
     editoptions:{dataUrl:'/path/to/generated/html/select'}
]
```

Then you just need to make sure that `/path/to/generated/html/select` returns all the right HTML code for a select element.